# Botão "Gostei/Like"

Tags: php, html

Quero fazer um botão no meu site com um contador ao lado e gostaria que a cada clique o contador aumentasse 1 número. Mas eu queria que ficasse salvo esse número de cliques num ficheiro `.txt` no servidor, e que todos pudessem clicar e ver esse contador.

Um botão *Like*, que só poderia ser clicado 1 vez por computador. Entendem?
Quero que os usuários avaliem o conteúdo do meu site com esse botão.

Comment: PHP, NodeJS, ASP...  que linguagem no lado do servidor? e que base de dados?

Comment: Gostaria que não usasse banco de dados, e o número fosse gravado em um arquivo de texto.

Comment: Ok, e que linguagem tens no lado do servidor? PHP, NodeJS, ASP...

Comment: PHP. :) Obrigado Sérgio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serão utilizado tres arquivos:

1 - principal.php, que exibirá o link para download e o numero de downloads

2 - download_arquivo.php - Este aumentará o contador em 1, fará o download do arquivo e redirecionará para o principal.php

3 - contador_arquivo.txt - Armazenará o numero de downloads

**ARQUIVO 1 - PRINCIPAL.PHP:**

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="download_arquivo">DOWNLOAD AQUI</a>
<br>N. de Downloads: <? include "contador_arquivo.txt"; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**ARQUIVO 2 - DOWNLOAD_ARQUIVO.PHP**

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="java script:history.back(-1)">">Voltar</a>
<?php
//Abre o contador de downloads e acrescenrta em 1
$fp = fopen("contador_arquivo.txt","r");
$visitas = fgets($fp,255);
$visitas++;
fclose($fp);
$fp = fopen("contador_arquivo.txt","w+");
fwrite($fp, $visitas);
fclose($fp);
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
//Redireciona para o arquivo de download
location.href="SEU_ARQUIVO.ZIP";
</script>
```

**ARQUIVO 3 - CONTADOR_ARQUIVO.TXT**

```
(escreva o numero 0 e salve o arquivo)
```

Fonte: [Contador Clicks](http://forum.wmonline.com.br/topic/6758-contador-de-downloads-e-cliques/)

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui o que eu queria!